# Add multiple values to data access object php

Tags: php, dao

I would like to add multiple values in a single Data Access Object: Is it possible? Here is the source code:

```
array_push($spec, array('TYPE' => 'FRANCHISE', 'VALEUR' => utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbFranchise'])));
array_push($spec, array('TYPE' => 'PRO', 'VALEUR' => utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbIsPro'])));
array_push($spec, array('TYPE' => 'CORNER', 'VALEUR' => utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbCorner'])));
array_push($spec, array('TYPE' => 'SHOWROOM', 'VALEUR' => utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbIsShowroom'])));

$spec->insert();
```

In Fact, I have a table whose name is SPECIFITE in the Polymag SCHEMA in database, and it is replacing the columns isshowroom, iscorner, franchise and ispro of polymag.magasin table.

So, Now the new table specificite is constituted by three columns: 'TYPE', 'VALEUR', and 'NUMMAG'. Nummag is also indicated in Polymag.magasin. Then, the 'TYPE' column will have four possible values: 'FRANCHISE', 'PRO', 'CORNER', 'SHOWROOM', and the columns VALEUR will contain its value.

Actually, the front code is written in "Action Script version 3" and the back is written in PHP.

Comment: Take some time to explain decently your issue, please.

Comment: Hello @Alberto, I edited the question

Comment: Are working with some specific framework/library? If not, then I'm not really sure what you're asking. A DAO is just an object with some properties. You can put what ever you want in them. However, I'm not sure what `$spec` is, since you're treating it as an array with `array_push()` but then as a class with `$spec->insertt()`

Comment: I'm working with a CMS (Content Management System) called e107. The problem is that the insertion fails

Comment: It's really important that you tell us that up front. Also, you should rewrite your question to be more clear. What data do you have, what data do you want (what should the result look like?). You might have that nested inside your question but it's pretty hard to understand =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
private function saveSpecificiteMagasin($isNewMag, $nummag, $type, $valeur, $debugSave) {
    $spec = dao::init('mdm.polymag.specificite');

    $spec->NUMMAG = $nummag;
    $spec->TYPE = $type;
    $spec->VALEUR = $valeur;

    if ($isNewMag == 0) {
        return $spec->update($debugSave);
    } else {
        return $spec->insert($debugSave);
    }
}
```

...

```
// On met à jour les spécificités liées au magasin
// On met à jour les spécificités liées au magasin
$retourSpecFranchise = $this->saveSpecificiteMagasin($isNewMag, $ret->NUMMAG, 'FRANCHISE', utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbFranchise']));
$retourSpecPro = $this->saveSpecificiteMagasin($isNewMag, $ret->NUMMAG, 'PRO', utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbIsPro']));
$retourSpecCorner = $this->saveSpecificiteMagasin($isNewMag, $ret->NUMMAG, 'CORNER', utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbCorner']));
$retourSpecShowRoom = $this->saveSpecificiteMagasin($isNewMag, $ret->NUMMAG, 'SHOWROOM', utf8_decode($_REQUEST['cmbIsShowroom']));
```